# Bootstrap Arabic HTML-headings render garbage in IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, arabic, html-heading

I am building an Arabic website using bootstrap-3.

I am getting everything fine -so far- with no problems **except** for the `html heading` e.g. `<h1>..</h1>`, `<h2>..</h2>`, `<h3>..</h3>`, `<h4>..</h4>`, `<h5>..</h5>`, and `<h6>..</h6>`

Whenever I add some Arabic text in the html heading the IE-10 render it as a garbage! While it works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Here is an image to show you what is the issue:

[image]

As you can see all Arabic letters are showing OK except for the html-heading.

And here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ar" dir="rtl">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ico/favicon.png">

    <title>موقع عربي</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap RTL -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap-rtl.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap-rtl-custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron">
              <h1>عنوان رئيسي</h1>
              <h2>عنوان فرعي</h2>
              <p>محتوى نص.. محتوى نص.. محتوى نص.. محتوى نص.. محتوى نص.. </p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">المزيد...</a></p>
            </div> <!-- /."jumbotron" -->
        </div> <!-- /.="container" -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Your help is appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like Bootstrap is using a font that doesn't include Arabic characters. Try switching the big heading's font to the font used in the smaller text.

Comment: I'd second this recommendation

Comment: You are the man, I was pulling my head hair..  I can't accept your answer yet, but in few minutes I will do. THANKS

Comment: I just add a new css file with name "IE-Compatibility" with below details body{font-family:arial !important;}